# is there such thing as e-shop script or plugin for cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cart

is there such thing as e-shop script or plugin for cakephp,

foe making e-shop parts or product display parts for websites

Comment: Unrelated to your question: but you should go into your profile, click through your old questions, and accept some answers for each. (There is a tick you can trigger on answers.)

Answer (score 0):

From my understaning, CakePHP is a framework - which means you'd have to code it yourself using the framework or find a free script.

If you mean what I think you mean by "e-shop", try http://mochashoppingcart.com/.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://www.enfew.com/7-best-shopping-cart-plugins-for-cakephp/